# Merge multiple arrays together if not null

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building a React App and am using Async Actions to make request to outside API's and bring in data into my app. I have 4 arrays that I need to merge together. Since I am using Async Actions the default values if theres no data is null. I want to check to see if the array is not null and if it has a value then merge it with the others into a single array. Once I have all the data into a single array I am going to use the includes method to see if any of the values are present in the array. Using the spread operator I don't think is going to work here as it will fail as null is not an iterable. Is there a way to do this with reduce to check through each of the 4 separate arrays make sure the value is not null and then combine them together into one array.

Comment: `[separate, arrays, here].reduce((acc, arr) => arr? acc.concat(arr): acc, []);`

Comment: `[...array1 || [], ...array2 || []]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question leads you to the answer. :)

Essentially you are asking how to filter all non-array inputs and then combine (or concatenate) them together into a new array.

A couple of notes on the following approach:

- For better stability in filtering, rather than using a blacklist (not `null`), use a whitelist (`Array.isArray`) to ensure only arrays are combined.
- The spread operator can be used to then create an arguments list for a new array's concat method.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2];
const arr2 = null;
const arr3 = [3,4];
const arr4 = [5];

const concat = (...arrays) => [].concat(...arrays.filter(Array.isArray));

console.log(concat(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4));
```

For a bit of fun, **if** the combined array needs to be unique values (assuming simple types for values) then including a quick cast to a `Set` and back to an `Array` can make that happen:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2];
const arr2 = null;
const arr3 = [3,4];
const arr4 = [4,5];

const concat = (...arrays) =>[].concat(...arrays.filter(Array.isArray));

const unique = (array) => [...new Set(array)];

const concated = concat(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4);
const uniqued = unique(concated);

console.log({concated, uniqued});
```

Comment: Really cool, very short! You're my competitor here, but I can't miss this awesome answer. Upvote!

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Ha. As long as we are all working to share knowledge there is no competition. That said, thanks for the upvote. 

Comment: Yeah, that's true ;)

Comment: The line where you actually concat is not used in the output. You are basicly just logging arr1, 2, 4 & 5.

Comment: @JonasPraem I’m not sure what you are referring to? Did you run the code? Please expand on your comment if you found an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one line solution (ES6).

At the first part, we merge all arrays, and then filter array elements - we include only "not null" values and exclude duplicates:

```js
const arr1 = [1, null, 6, 'q'],
      arr2 = null,
      arr3 = [1, 1, null, 1],
      arr4 = ['e', 'q', 6, 1, null];

const final = []
  .concat(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)
  .filter((item, i, arr) => item && arr.indexOf(item) === i);

console.log(final); // Expected output: [1, 6, "q", "e"]
```

Comment: It's not about members of those arrays possibly being null, it's about `arr2 === null`;

Comment: @connexo, provided code will work with `const arr2 = null;` as well, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign your arrays to properties of an object  `obj`, you can simply iterate over the object :

```js
const a = ["a", "1"], b = null, c = ["c", 78], d = []

const obj = { a, b, c, d }

let res = []

for(let key in obj) {
 res = res.concat(Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? obj[key] : []);  
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = null

var c = [...a||[], ...b||[]]

console.log(c)
```